# Authenticity Of A Narration About Hazrat Khadijah (Radhi'allahu'anha) In A Book Called "Tarikh"?

Tags: authenticity, seerah

> They also say that Khadijah sent a message to the Messenger of God
> [Muhammad] inviting him to take her, meaning that they should marry.
> She was a highly respected woman, and the whole of Quraysh [tribe]
> would have been eager to marry her and would have spent much money to
> that end had they aspired to it. She called her father to her house,
> plied him with wine until he was drunk, slaughtered a cow, anointed
> him with perfume and clothed him in a striped robe; then she sent for
> the Messenger of God and his uncles and, when they came in, her father
> married him to her. When her father recovered from his intoxication,
> he said, “What is this meat, this perfume, and this garment?” She
> replied, “You have married me to Muhammad b. ‘Abdallah.” “I have not
> done so,” he said. “Would I do this, when the greatest men of Mecca
> have asked for you and I have not agreed?”

This is found somewhere in Tarikh, vol. 6, p. 49 but I do not know where.

Comment: Is there anymore information availbale? Could you share the source of the quote? There are many books that come to mind: Tarikh of at-Tabari, Tarikh Baghdad of al-Khatib al-Baghdadi, Tarikh Dimasqh of ibn 'Asakir just to cite some. The issue is it basically could be any book about history or biographies as the term Tarikh is somewhat lenient. Furthermore Khadija' s father was already dead when she married Muhammad according to ibn Hajar.

Comment: @Medi1Saif - Salam brother, this narration is found in Tarikh Tabari, volume 6, page no. 49. You can find it here:- https://docs.google.com/viewer?url=https://muslim-library.com/books/2019/05/en_Tabari_Volume_06.pdf